# PowerShell Regex DisplayName

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to put a bunch of users through a regex query that look for 'IM' or '(IM)' at the end of their DisplayName and then removes it. I'll be exporting first of course for backup.

I'm have used the .contains method but if I use that any Tim's or Imogen's might get a little annoyed at me.

```
$users = Get-DistributionGroupMember 'DGName' | ? { $_.RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' }
$mailboxes = $users | Get-Mailbox
$output = @()

$mailboxes | Select-Object Alias, DisplayName | Export-Csv D:\Scripts\PreDisplayNames.csv -NoTypeInformation

foreach ($mb in $mailboxes){
    if ($mb.DisplayName.EndsWith(" (IM)")){
        $newString = $mb.DisplayName.TrimEnd(" (IM)")
        $newStringTD = $mb.DisplayName.TrimEnd(" (IM)") + " (TD)"
        $resultstring =  "Setting DisplayName to $newString"
        $mb | Set-Mailbox -DisplayName $newString -WhatIf

    }
    elseif($mb.DisplayName.EndsWith(" IM")){
        $newString = $mb.DisplayName.TrimEnd(" IM")
        $newStringTD = $mb.DisplayName.TrimEnd(" (IM)") + " (TD)"
        $resultstring = "Setting DisplayName to $newString"
        $mb | Set-Mailbox -DisplayName $newString -WhatIf
    }
    else{
        $newString = 'DNIncorrect'
        $resultstring = 'Incorrect DisplayName'
    }
    $props = [ordered]@{
            'DisplayName' = $mb.DisplayName
            'NewDisplayName' = $newString
            'NewDisplayName TD' = $newStringTD
            }
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
    $output += $object
}

$output | Export-Csv "D:\scripts\DisplayNames.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: having trouble pasting code but might have answered.

`$newString = $string.DisplayName.TrimEnd(" (IM)")`... so IF through either iteration and then a last else to take care of any that don't fit that convention (it's a large environment)

Comment: WARNING: `.trim()` deletes ALL matching characters! So even `MI` will be deleted!

Comment: Ahh.... so this is why I posted... cheers restless1987. would you suggest a better way?

Comment: actually sorry should say the If statments say    if ($mb.DisplayName.EndsWith(" (IM)"))... so there's one for IM and on for (IM) and then an else. would that catch it or does EndsWith cover MI too?

Comment: the regex wouldn't be a problem, could you add some code to (safely) reproduce the issue?

Comment: Even with a regex, you'd have issue with someone named `Theo Verbatim`

Comment: not if it is in uppercase `(IM|\(IM\))$` as OP stated

Comment: sorry all I first time posting on the site and didn't see the edit button so I've been trying to paste code in comments :( newby bash away. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Theres no need for a regex here, just use a -like to filter your objects when you collect the mailboxes

`$mailboxes = $users | Get-Mailbox | Where-object {($_.DisplayName -like "*IM") -or ($_.DisplayName -like "*(IM)")}`

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yep I was just concerned about any that aren't following convention as it's a big environment. Guess though the likelhood of not following convention AND having a name ending in IM is very unlikely so you're probably right

Comment: Can you be sure that the IM or (IM) will always be capital letters?  if so use -clike rather than -like, that should eliminate a good number of your false positives.  Also you mention a convention but I don't think I see one in the original question, if you can show me what its supposed to look like I can try to put together a regex for you that will let you ignore things that don't match(or generate a report of the non-matching names that also have IM in them to review manually)

Comment: Cheers again Mike. I didn't even know about clike I really need to use get-help more. By convention I mean they should end in IM or (IM) but wanted to be sure in case some don't as I'm target a group. I think what you've written before and as you say use clike instead of like is going to do the trick... thanks again mate

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted a regex I normally use the following to generate a regex for specific words. It may work for you situation.

```
$Eliminate = @("bak", "error", "research","Retry")
[regex]$eliminate_regex = '(?i)(' + (($Eliminate | foreach { [regex]::escape($_) }) -join "|") + ')'
```